# NameError about not defined

Tags: python-2.7

```
abc_str = raw_input('A B C: ')
print abc_str
abc_list = abc_str.split()
print abc_list
# suuuum = 0
for i in range(3):
    suuuum += int(abc_list[i])
print suuuum

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tttest.py", line 7, in <module>
    suuuum += int(abc_list[i])
NameError: name 'suuuum' is not defined
```

If I omit the sharp, everything will be ok. But why should I define "suuuum" first?
My answer is because I called "suuuum" before I assign it to an object. Then I tried a += 8 in Terminal,as followed:

```
>>> a += 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

This is my thought. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. When you write `x += 1`, it means as below :

```
x = x + 1
```

So, if you didn't defined `x` already, you got an error. Because the interpreter can't calculate the right side of equal.

In your program above, when you commented `suuuum`, you got the error because you have the following:

```
for i in range(3):
    suuuum = suuuum + int(abc_list[i])
```

And thus for the first i, the `suuuum` in the right side is undefined.

Comment: Thank you! (I tried to upvote but it says I need 15 reputation :\)